# Adding two data-frames with different values in a common column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two data frames. I need to add them to calculate the total number of matches played and perform further calculations from the answer. But every time I try to add them, some of the rows have Nan values.

[Image of the two given dataframes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t2OuJ.png)

The result of adding them comes out like this

[Image of the output on adding the two dataframes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sspuv.png)

How do I add them without getting NaN values???

Comment: [please don't put images of code or data in the question, instead post them as text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question) so people can reproduce your question

Comment: I am sorry about that. I didn't know how to format it so it was readable as code.

Comment: reading [how to produce good reproducible pandas examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) would help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**sum after joining and grouping by teams:**

```
ipl=pd.concat([ipl17,ipl18]).groupby('Team').sum().reset_index()
```

---

```
print(ipl)
```

**Output:**

```
   Team  Matches  Won  Lost  Tied  N/R  Points    NRR   For  Against
0   CSK       14    9     5     0    0      18  0.253  2488     2433
1    DD       28   11    17     0    0      22 -0.734  4516     4559
2    GL       14    4    10     0    0       8 -0.412  2406     2472
3   KKR       28   16    12     0    0      32  0.571  4692     4725
4  KXIP       28   13    15     0    0      26 -0.379  4417     4488
5    MI       28   16    12     0    0      32  1.101  4787     4524
6   RCB       28    9    18     0    1      19 -1.170  4167     4416
7   RPS       14    9     5     0    0      18  0.176  2180     2165
8    RR       14    7     7     0    0      14 -0.250  2130     2141
9   SRH       28   17    10     0    1      35  0.753  4451     4311
```

---

**Explanation:**

Using `concat` join the two `dataframe`. using `groupby('name')` are grouped by `Team`. Subsequently, the sum is obtained for each team. Then `reset_index` is used to transform the `index` (Team) into `columns`. If you prefer the latter you can skip it.